# How to retrive Stripe card ID added via Stripe customer portal?

Tags: stripe-payments

How to retrive Stripe card ID added via Stripe customer portal?

It is not visible when I try to access it via:

```
test = stripe.Customer.list_sources(
    'cus_Izw...',
     object="card",
     limit=3,
)
```

I see this in the response:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "object": "list",
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_Izw.../sources"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cards that are added through the Customer Portal are PaymentMethods not Sources. In order to list them, you can use the `/v1/payment_methods`. In Python it would look something like:

```py
stripe.PaymentMethod.list(
  customer="cus_xxx",
  type="card",
)
```

Comment: Looks good, but there is no card ID in the response, for example: card_Izza42koJ6LKGpF

Comment: Yes, the PaymentMethod is a pm_xxx, and card info is part of the card attribute: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object?#payment_method_object-card